# A phrase that means "someone who used to be a servant but suddenly became the lord of the family" meaning

Tags: phrase-requests

A phrase that means "someone who used to be a servant but suddenly became the lord of the family" meaning. Someone who used to be of low ranking but due to certain factors, got promoted to a higher ranked person suddenly. Is there any phrase or words to describe that?

More emphasis on the difference in rank/status and less on the wealth part.

Comment: ***Rags to riches***, and the opposite direction, ***prince to pauper***.

Comment: If the person is additionally arrogant about their new stature: 'Jumped-up' or 'Upstart'

Answer (score 2):

It's a [Cinderella story](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cinderella_story)

> Used in reference to a situation in which a person, team, etc., of low status or importance unexpectedly achieves great success or public recognition.
>
> ‘the team ended their Cinderella story with a 6–5 triumph’

[Oxford]

Also see: [Cinderella Man](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Cinderella%20Man)